# Ajax page fails with undefined variable error message

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm just trying to write my first ajax enabled page.  Needless to say, I've run into a problem.  And I think it reveals a fundamental misunderstanding of how ajax is supposed to work. 
Here's a description of what i'm trying to accomplish. 
I have a page with a table containing records from my database.  When the user clicks on my refresh button, i want to requery the database for all records and display them without refreshing the page. 
Here's my controller:

```
  class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
          parent::__construct();           
          $this->load->helper('date');
          $this->load->helper('url');
   }

   public function index()
   {

          $this->load->model('locations_model');
          $emess = '';
          $data['clienthistory'] = $this->locations_model->get_locations();
          $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
          $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

          $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
   }

   public function index2()
   {

          echo('inside the getlatest method');

          $this->load->model('locations_model');
          $data['clienthistory'] = $this->locations_model->get_locations();

          //build HTML table to send back to view
          $data['latestdashboardHTML']= "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'><thead>";
          $data['latestdashboardHTML']=$data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "<tr><th>IP</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Updated</th></tr></thead><tbody>"    ;     

      foreach ($data['clienthistory'] as $histitem)
      {
                 $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "<tr>";              
                 $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "<td>" & $histitem['network'] & "</td>";
                 $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "<td>" & $histitem['name'] & "</td>";
                 $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "<td>" & $histitem['lastupdated'] & "</td>";
                 $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "</tr>";                    
          }

          $data['latestdashboardHTML'] = $data['latestdashboardHTML'] & "</tbody></table>";
          $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
             echo ($data['latestdashboardHTML'])   ;            

          $this->load->view($data['main_content'] );

   }
 }
```

And here's the code in my view:

```
<h2>Client Dashboard</h2>
<br/><p>
          <?php echo form_open('Dashboard/index');    

   echo form_submit('submit', 'Refresh Data', 'id="submit" class="btn-primary"');
   ?>
</p>
      <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="span12" id="ajaxcontainer">

                       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                       <thead>
                              <tr>
                                     <th>IP</th>
                                     <th>Name</th>
                                     <th>Last Updated</th>

                              </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                              <?php foreach ($clienthistory as $histitem): ?>

                                  <tr>
                                     <td><?php echo $histitem['network'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $histitem['name'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $histitem['lastupdated'] ?></td>

                                  </tr>

                              <?php endforeach ?>

                       </tbody>
                       </table>


                 </div>

      </div><!--/row-->

<?php

          echo form_close();
?>

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-transition.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-alert.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-button.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bs-typeahead.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#submit').click(function() {
          alert('here');
          $.ajax({

                 url:"<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/index2'); ?>",
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function(msg) {
                       alert(msg);
                       $('#ajaxcontainer').replaceWith(msg);
                 }
          });

          return false;       
   });
   </script>
```

Problem:
the first time through, the page loads properly.  all records show up with the correct values.  But when i try the refresh button, the javascript executes, calls the index2 method.. but then it fails in the view on line 22 - which is where I'm trying to loop through the clienthistory array. 
The error message is:  Undefined variable: clienthistory.

SO here's my question.  I thought the way ajax worked was that it only updated a section of the page.  So I guess I don't understand why it's "redo-ing" this part of the view.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, and more importantly, if my understanding of ajax is correct. I'd also prefer it if i could combine the two methods into one... i tried but had some problems so I ended up just copying index() to index2() and just working with that.

The other behavior that I'm noticing is that the title "

## Client Dashboard

" as well as the button is showing up twice when execute the ajax method. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. In index2() i'm loading the view again.
i shouldn't reload the view.  i just need to pass the html string to the caller.
this in part resolves my problem.

so specifically in my controller i replaced:

```
      $this->load->view($data['main_content'] );
```

with

```
      return $htmlstring;
```

where $htmlstring contains the same string as $data['latestdashboardHTML']

the other problem is that i needed to specify the dataType that i was expected back from the controller.

so i added the following line to my .ajax function:

```
     dataType: 'html'
```

Finally, I read online somewhere that it's not a good idea to have the controller create any HTML.  this is supposed to be the job of the view. 
i guess i will try to pass an array from controller to view.  and then have the jquery code recreate the contents of my div.
thanks